# Copy IPython's pretty printing of results

Tags: python, ipython, pretty-print

When displaying results in [IPython](https://github.com/ipython) (without using `print()`), nested objects gets an easy-to-view formatting. Is there a way to create/copy a function in Python with the same pretty formatting functionalities as IPython uses? I have been trying to look through their code for a possible module to import, but it seems like an impossible task. Would it be possible to write one yourself?

IPython example:

```
In [1]: {'Mario': {'Stats': [63, 10, 69, 24, 82], 'Result': [(2, 7, 5, {'ids': 
[46737432927499418861568L, 61421050754327147184128L, 46239274047769245908992L]})]}, 
'Luigi': {'Results': [(7, 9, 6, {'ids': [20471482889415933558784L, 
87284089722223609249792L, 27117156251036496691200L]})], 'Stats': [14, 71, 93, 49, 53]}}

Out[1]: 
{'Luigi': {'Results': [(7,
    9,
    6,
    {'ids': [20471482889415933558784L,
      87284089722223609249792L,
      27117156251036496691200L]})],
  'Stats': [14, 71, 93, 49, 53]},
 'Mario': {'Result': [(2,
    7,
    5,
    {'ids': [46737432927499418861568L,
      61421050754327147184128L,
      46239274047769245908992L]})],
  'Stats': [63, 10, 69, 24, 82]}}
```

**[EDIT]** I know of the `pprint` module, but it does not do indentations the same way as IPython does (I don't want the indentation level of child elements to be dependent on their parent).

What `pprint` outputs:

```
{'Luigi': {'Results': [(7,
                        9,
                        6,
                        {'ids': [20471482889415933558784L,
                                 87284089722223609249792L,
                                 27117156251036496691200L]})],
           'Stats': [14, 71, 93, 49, 53]},
 'Mario': {'Result': [(2,
                       7,
                       5,
                       {'ids': [46737432927499418861568L,
                                61421050754327147184128L,
                                46239274047769245908992L]})],
           'Stats': [63, 10, 69, 24, 82]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython uses its own formatter, [`IPython.core.formatters.PlainTextFormatter`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.formatters.html#IPython.core.formatters.PlainTextFormatter), for output pretty-printing. If you want to use it, you'll either need to install IPython or copy the [`IPython.lib.pretty`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html#module-IPython.lib.pretty) source. With IPython installed, you can use

```
from IPython.lib.pretty import pprint

pprint(your_big_ugly_data_structure)
```

If you want to copy the source, it's [available on Github](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/IPython/lib/pretty.py). It looks like the only dependencies on the rest of IPython are trivial to remove. Take note of the [license](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/about/license_and_copyright.html).

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module. Usually simply using `from pprint import pprint` and then using `pprint()` instead of `print()` can get you decent results; its output can be customized as well if you read over the module docs.

Comment: Thanks! However, the problem is that pprint creates indents very differently from IPython. I need child elements on new lines to be indented `i` characters where `i` is the child element level, and not dependent on the indentation of the parent element. I don't think that's possible with `pprint` without further formatting?